# JavaとTomcatのバージョン

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

JavaでPleiadesを使って簡単な画面の開発を行いたいと思っています。そこで質問なんですが、Javaのバージョン1.8で開発を行いたい場合、Tomcatのバージョンは7.0で問題ないのでしょうか。またコンパイラー準拠レベルは1.8にするのがよいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4):

Tomcat の [Which Version](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) のページに Tomcat と Java の関連表があります。
これを見る限り、Java8 で開発する場合に Tomcat7 でも問題ないと思います。
Java8 で開発するので準拠レベルも 1.8 で良いはずです。

Comment: apache-tomcat-9.0.50 の場合は、JDK は何が可能でしょうか？

Comment: Tomcatの[Which Version](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)のページに`Latest Released Version=9.0.50`の行で`Supported Java Versions=8 and later`と書かれています。この文脈ではJavaとJDKはほぼ同義と考えて良いのでJDK8以降が使えます。

Comment: 解答欄やコメントでのご質問はそれに対する回答を返しにくく、視認性や検索性も悪いので新たな質問を作成することをお勧めします。もしOracleJDKとOpenJDKの区分も質問内容に含むならばその旨を質問文に追記してみてください。